# Query to get distinct values only on group of columns

Tags: sql, db2

If I have the following table:

```
Table name: FOO
ID | NUMBER | EVENT | NAME | CAR
1  |   12   | OFFER | Adam | VW
2  |   13   | ORDER | Adam | VW
3  |   11   | OFFER | Adam | BMW
4  |   12   | OFFER | Adam | BMW
5  |   3    | OFFER | Adam | BMW
6  |   1    | ORDER | Mark | Mercedes
7  |   1    | ORDER | Mark | BMW
```

The query should return

```
Result name: FOO
ID | NUMBER | EVENT | NAME | CAR
2  |   13   | ORDER | Adam | VW
4  |   12   | OFFER | Adam | BMW
6  |   1    | ORDER | Mark | Mercedes
7  |   1    | ORDER | Mark | BMW
```

The following rules apply:

```
- Get the records which have DISTINCT NAME AND CAR
- If more than one record with the same NAME AND CAR exists, get the one with MAX NUMBER
- ID, NUMBER, EVENT should not count towards the DISTINCT row rule
```

The DB platform is DB2, but any SQL is good, at this point, as long as it's pure SQL.

I do not manage to get the DISTINCT rule to apply to only (NAME, CAR), on the whole row, and if more than one row exists with the same (NAME, CAR), get the row with highest NUMBER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure, unadulterated ansi-92 SQL:

```
select t1.*
from Foo t1
inner join
(
select Name, Car, max(number) as maxNo
from Foo
group by Name, Car
) x2
on t1.Name = x2.Name
and t1.Car = x2.car
and t1.Number = x2.maxNo
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you came up with it so fast...!!!! Will mark as accepted answer in a few minutes, when it allows me

Comment: @Wilhelm Sorban if performance is important make sure to run a performance test betwen the solutions

Comment: I definitely will! :) But as I mentioned in the OP, I needed a pure SQL, that would work in most database technologies.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
with temp as (
select id, number, event, name, car,
       rownumber() over (partition by name, car order by number desc) as rownum
  from foo
 )
 select id, number, event, name, car from temp 
 where rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a group by can help.

```
select id, max(number), event, name, car from foo group by name, car
```

This works in MySQL, but not in DB. Apparently MySQL is much more straight-forward.

Comment: This will not work, as you need to also group by event, id

Comment: try there... create table foo (id int, number int, event varchar(255), name varchar(255), car varchar(255));

insert into foo (id, number, event, name, car) values (1, 12, 'offer', 'adam', 'vw');
insert into foo values (2, 13, 'order', 'adam', 'vw');
insert into foo values (3, 14, 'offer', 'adam', 'bmw');
insert into foo values (4, 15, 'offer', 'adam', 'bmw');
insert into foo values (5, 16, 'offer', 'adam', 'bmw');
insert into foo values (6, 17, 'order', 'mark', 'vw');
insert into foo values (7, 18, 'order', 'mark', 'bmw');

Comment: You are right, it works in MySQL, but not DB2... You will need to edit your answer, so I can upvote it. My appologies, and good job!

Comment: Ok, haven't db2.  then the subquery is the best way for your problem.

Comment: I'm quite sure this wont work in MS SQL, and Oracle either. Still, nice to know there are platforms that accept this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this SELECT statement

```
SELECT FOO.ID, F.Number, Foo.Event, f.Name, f.Car
FROM FOO INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(Number) AS Number, Name, Car 
    FROM FOO
    GROUP BY Name, Car
) F ON FOO.Number = F.Number AND FOO.Name = F.Name AND Foo.Car = F.Car
ORDER BY FOO.ID
```